# Refactoring Service injection/instantiation in Grails application

Tags: grails

The app I'm working on has one service that is referenced like this:

```
private def widgetServ = new WidgetService()
```

in another service. Methods are called on `widgetServ` like this:

```
def aVar = widgetServ.SomeMethod()
```

Inside `widgetServ` sql connection is created using this:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(...
```

Here are some issues we are facing:

Since we use 'new' we can't have implicit transactions by using `static transactional = true`, according to Grails docs. While attempting to upgrade Grails from 1.3.7 to 2.4.4 we noticed that creating the sql variable above that an error is thrown due to the system not being able to find the jdbc driver. 
We'd like to not use new and instead inject the `WidgetService`.

Question is that has anyone ran into this and can you post any pitfalls?

Another service in the system has similar problems but is worse since it is used like a POGO and has 140+ instance where it is created new. Plus, some controllers inject it and create it new.
What approach should we use in removing all 'new' creations of the service? The system does have issues with stale references and missing data that can possibly be caused by lack of transaction management in these services.

Comment: Note: The second service I'm referencing has multiple constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't use "new" here because objects created like that are totally unaware of Spring context, so they don't know anything about configs, datasource etc.
The question is, why did you do it like that? and is there any reason not you regular dependency injection? It wouldn't be very painful, it would just need to change all

```
private def widgetServ = new WidgetService()
```

to

```
private WidgetService widgetServ
```

and maybe refactor this field names to `widgetService` (easily done in IDE)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm coming into the project new and found it like this. The job now is to correct it. A bigger job is the other service I allude to that has multiple constructors and is created 'new' 140+ times in the application.